# How can I send more than just one message?

Tags: java, vonage

I want to develop a simple app that enables me to send SMS to several numbers 
and from several numbers.

In the code below, I send from number 5555 to 6666.  I want to send, for example, also from number 7777 to number 8888.

What do I need to add to the code?

Meanwhile, I tried to copy `TextMessage` message but without success.

```
package getstarted;

import com.nexmo.client.NexmoClient;
import com.nexmo.client.auth.AuthMethod;
import com.nexmo.client.auth.TokenAuthMethod;
import com.nexmo.client.sms.SmsSubmissionResult;
import com.nexmo.client.sms.messages.TextMessage;

public class SendSMS {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AuthMethod auth = new TokenAuthMethod("xxxxx","yyyy");
        NexmoClient client = new NexmoClient(auth);

        TextMessage message = new TextMessage("5555", "6666", "Hello from Nexmo!");
        SmsSubmissionResult[] responses = client.getSmsClient().submitMessage(message);

        for (SmsSubmissionResult response : responses) {
            System.out.println(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and edit your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quick, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 2):

Just instantiate another `TextMessage`:

```
TextMessage message2 = new TextMessage("7777", "8888", "Hello from Nexmo!");
SmsSubmissionResult[] responses2 = client.getSmsClient().submitMessage(message2);

for (SmsSubmissionResult response : responses2) {
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

Comment: feel free to accept the answer if it worked for you!